# Is possible to replace a generated PDF using itextsharp if it exists?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itext

I am using the code below to generate a pdf and save it to a server location. How would I or can I replace the file if it exists? So if the directory contains a pdf if the same "myUniqueFileName" that it replaces it with the same file name? Thank you

```
Dim Doc1 As New Document
    Dim path As String = "\\server\pdfs\"
    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) Then

        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
    End If
    Dim myUniqueFileName = String.Format("{0}.pdf", random)
    Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(path & myUniqueFileName, FileMode.Create))

    Doc1.Open()
    Dim test As String
    test = Session("PDF")
    Dim PDFHeader As String
    PDFHeader = Session("Header")
    Dim imagepath As String = Server.MapPath(".") & "/images/Header.png"
    Dim image As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath)
    image.ScalePercent(70.0F)
    Dim line1 As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator(0.0F, 100.0F, BaseColor.BLACK, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1)

    Doc1.Add(image)
    Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(PDFHeader))
    Doc1.Add(New Chunk(line1))
    Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(test))
    Doc1.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Nm, I was able to use the same logic and it will recreate the file using FileMode.Create